# Patch DLL in AX 2012

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

We have a customer that has an old version of some software installed.
There is a problem and we have a fix for it. Only we can't deploy it at the customer.

I'm not an AX guy myself, but I don't understand the problem either.
We have decompiled the "old" dll, made a small change, recompiled it again with the **same version number**s etcetera and **signed the dll with the same key**.
If I open both versions with dotPeek I see they have the exact same assembly name.

Then when I replace the "old" dll with the "new" dll and run the AX code I get following errors:

- "Assembly containing type 'namespace.type' is not referenced."
- "Object 'CLRObject' could not be created."
- "A critical error has occurred in function [nameOfAxFunction]."

So why does it not take the new dll?
Does AX do a check on the hash of each dll that it load and therefore block my new version?
Do we need to recompile the AX code ... ?

Also in the AX function it fails when creating a new instance of a type that is in our modified assembly. So it's not even that we access another dll that fails to load our new dll, we go directly from AX to the new version of the dll.

Ps:

- I have double checked and the type is still in the assembly.
- Assemblies replaced in: 
  `"Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Client\Bin" & 
  "Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\[env-name]\bin"`

Comment: I also found an article about the [AOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/hot-swapping-of-net-assemblies-in-the-aos) which would explain the behavior if it would not take my new dll, and keep executing the old code. But since I get an error after replacing the dll I assume it actually tries to load the new version... (Also I do restart the AX client.)

Comment: Have you tried adding it in the AOT? You may be the older version in the AOT

Comment: Under `\References` in the AOT, right click and `Add Reference` and try that. Do in a Dev environment and make sure you know what you're doing.